# Jwplayer buffer can not stop

Tags: jwplayer

I came to China, a jwplayer buffer problem troubled me, I hope to get help here
This is the case:
I use HTTP+MP4

1. I set up the following code

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="LAplEpgDNWgqrP1EoacHsBSb1Wq7Bgj2WmUSrA==";</script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="myElement">Loading the player ...</div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
           playerInstance.setup({
               file: "http://183.131.82.138/play/4607c979e58330787a603a94474f7d44386eaeec.mp4",
               bufferChange:1,
               height: 360,
               width: 640
           });
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. I set the `bufferChange` to `1`, when the jwplayer is playing, will buffer certain data, when to reach a certain size, the buffer will be suspended, which is what I want to see the effect.
3. The problem is that when the suspension of the press jwplayer, the movie will be suspended, but the buffer will start, and has been a buffer full movie. I don't want to be so as it will waste my server traffic. I want to press jwplayer to pause, and the buffer is stopped. Or when you play, press jwplayer to pause, buffer to a certain size, stop buffer.

Hopefully I can get some help here.

I am... 谢谢

Answer (score 0):

It does not look as though it is possible with JW Player as of version 7.2.4, per the following comments at the noted link.

```
JW PlayerUser  
Apr 04, 2014 10:23AM EDT 0rated :
Hi Ethan,
Is it possible to stop the video download after few seconds if user "paused" the playback?
I saw youtube has a "stop video download" option if I right click on the video player. even on pause it stop the buffering after few seconds.



Ethan FeldmanJW Player Support Agent   
Apr 04, 2014 10:23AM EDT 0rated :
It isn’t possible, sorry.
```

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062626-stop-buffering